# Handling multiple values in regular expression extractor when output count varies

Tags: jmeter

I’m using regular expression extractor in jmeter to capture a value that I’ll be passing in the next http request.

The value captured is say `request_1`, `request_2` etc. 
the total number of requests that are being captured varies. I.e., the total count for the output of the regular expression extractor varies.

In the http request, based on the count value _matchnbr I need to loop and assign different requests (`request_1` or `request_2` etc) in the http request for each iteration. This http request will also be in a separate thread group.

1. Please help with creating the right code to handle this loop logic. I don’t want to use the for loop controller as I’m facing stack overflow error while running in non GUI mode.
2. Please advise on how to make the output from regular expression extractor to be available for a http request in a separate thread group.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass the output of the regular expression extractor from one [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to another you need to:

1. Convert the relevant JMeter Variables into JMeter Properties in the first Thread Group. You can do it by adding a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the end of the first Thread Group and use the following code:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   vars.entrySet().each { var ->
       if (var.getKey().startsWith("foo")) {
            props.put('user-' + ctx.getThreadNum() + '-' + var.getKey(), var.getValue())
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the second Thread Group you need to perform the opposite operation, convert JMeter Properties to JMeter Variables back:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   props.entrySet().each { prop ->
       if (prop.getKey().startsWith('user-' + ctx.getThreadNum() + '-foo')) {
           vars.put(prop.getKey().substring(prop.getKey().lastIndexOf('-') + 1), prop.getValue())
       }
   }
   ```
3. Replace `foo` with your original JMeter Variable reference name

In the above script:

- `vars` - stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, provides programmatic read/write access to all JMeter Variables in scope
- `props` - JMeter Properties, basically an instance of [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on above and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands.

P.S. It's better to use [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) for iterating Regular Expression Extractor's results.